# Ошибка при сборке проекта в CMake

Tags: qt, qt5, cmake

При сборке configurator (проект veyon 3.99.4) выскакивает ошибка:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (QT5_WRAP_CPP): Unknown CMake command "QT5_WRAP_CPP".

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt: No cmake_minimum_required command is present. A line of code such as

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
should be added at the top of the file. The version specified may be lower if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project. For more information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000". This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

P.S: Версия Qt 5.9.3, Win10, CMake 3.10. Ссылка на проект: https://github.com/veyon/veyon/releases/ Также поискал в документации(http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html), что описано по данной ошибке. Попробовал CMake ниже 2.8.9, все равно та же ошибка. Поиск по гуглу и eng stackoverflow ответов не дал.

Comment: В тексте ошибки сказано, что надо добавить первой строкой файла директиву `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION версия)`.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае стоит обратить внимание на предупреждение:

```
No cmake_minimum_required command is present.
```

Так как все "правильные" проекты ставят вызов "cmake_minimum_required" практически в самом начале `CMakeLists.txt`, данное предупреждение сигнализирует о том, что вы запускаете `cmake` с неправильной директорией исходных файлов.

В случае с данным проектом, `cmake` должен запускаться из директории верхнего уровня, запуск из поддиректории "configurator" не предусмотрен.